# Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list' when do LDA in R

Tags: r

```
mydat=structure(list(spent = c(73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 
73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 
29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 73.71, 73.71, 73.71, 
73.71, 73.71, 73.71, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 
73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 
29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 73.71, 73.71, 73.71, 73.71, 
73.71, 73.71), realpurchase_cash = c(501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 
506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 511, 512, 513, 514, 515, 516, 517, 518, 
519, 520, 521, 522, 523, 524, 525, 526, 527, 528, 73.5, 73.5, 
73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 29.74, 
29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 
29.74, 73.71, 73.71, 73.71, 73.71, 73.71, 73.71), id = c(123L, 
123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 
123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 
123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 
124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 
124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L
), flag = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("spent", 
"realpurchase_cash", "id", "flag"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-56L))
```

i want perform Linear discriminant analysis. (lda function  comes from MASS library)

here my code

```
index <- sample(1:nrow(mydat),round(0.70*nrow(mydat)))
train <- mydat[index,]
test <- mydat[-index,]
library("MASS")
fit=lda(flag~spent+realpurchase_cash, mydat, subset = train)
library("caret") 
str(mydat)
library(InformationValue)
predicted <- predict(fit,test,type='response')
optCutOff <- optimalCutoff(test$flag, predicted)[1] 
confusionMatrix(test$flag, predicted, threshold = optCutOff)
```

but after this string

```
fit=lda(flag~spent+realpurchase_cash, mydat, subset = train)
```

i get the error

```
Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

How to fix this error. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subset` wants a vector and you give him a data frame (i.e. a list). Do

```
lda(flag ~ spent + realpurchase_cash, mydat, subset=index)
```

or, since `train` is already your desired subset, just

```
lda(flag ~ spent + realpurchase_cash, data=train)
```

Comment: but how to be with confusionMatrix(test$flag, predicted), when i run this, i get the error  Error in ifelse(predictedScores < threshold, 0, 1) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double', how can i create confusionMatrix?

Comment: That's pretty the same error. Type `?InformationValue::confusionMatrix` to open the documentation. From this you can conclude that your second argument `predictedScores` needs a vector. Then open `predicted` or type `str(predicted)`. What do you have?

Comment: but if i want via table . it is more easy, but here error :( table(test$flag,predicted)
Error in table(test$flag, predicted) : 
  all arguments must have the same length

Comment: Compare `length(test$flag)`, `length(predicted)`, `length(predicted$class)` ;)